# How to pass dynamic variables to my .EXE?

Tags: php, variables, exe, nsis

I am creating an .exe with NSIS and am trying to figure out how to pass variables into the .exe from the download link.

For example I would have 1 .exe on www.mysite.com/download.php but if they downloaded it from `www.mysite.com/download.php?name=jimmy` that variable "jimmy" would be able to be read and used inside the NSIS .exe

Comment: And what if I download your exe from my linux box, for which a exe is just a plain text file ? And then copy it over to my Windows ? There is no way what you want to achieve can be done. You can pass a variable to script when you execute them, but not when you download them.

Comment: How would you you recommend passing variables to an .exe then?  Do I need to have my server www.mysite.com/download.php?name=jimmy compile the .exe with the variable?

Answer (score 0):

You can append any data you want to the end of the .exe without corrupting it and then read [this data in the installer](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/ReadCustomerData)...